# azure Live event without definition of IP or IPRange- android

Tags: android, azure, live-streaming, azure-media-services

I am building app who open live stream to server (Azure media service in the cloud) 
I used suitable SDK for that.
I am following  [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-java/blob/master/LiveIngest/LiveEventWithDVR/src/main/java/sample/LiveEventWithDVR.java) link. 
I need to know if it is necessary to provide IP address or IP range for liveEvent like in example or not?

```
IPRange allAllowIPRange = new IPRange().withName("AllowAll").withAddress("0.0.0.0").withSubnetPrefixLength(0);
List<IPRange> listIPRanges = new ArrayList<>();
listIPRanges.add(allAllowIPRange);

// Create the LiveEvent input IP access control.
LiveEventInputAccessControl liveEventInputAccess = new LiveEventInputAccessControl();
liveEventInputAccess.withIp(new IPAccessControl().withAllow(listIPRanges));



   //live event instance 
   LiveEvent liveEvent = manager.liveEvents().define(liveEventName)
                        .withExistingMediaservice(config.getResourceGroup(), config.getAccountName())
                        .withAutoStart(true)
                        .withInput(new 
LiveEventInput().withStreamingProtocol(LiveEventInputProtocol.RTMP).withAccessControl(**liveEventInputAccess**))
                        .create();
```

the question: Is it necessary to define and set `liveEventInputAccess` instance in `liveEvent` instance?

if it is necessary so how I can do it without fix Ip Address? randomly

Comment: Has your problem been solved?

Comment: It is possible to create live event without IP or IP range and because I give to the client the ability to open live event so I work only with the sdk without set properties directly in the portal

Comment: I know, I just tell you when to use restrict ip. Because I don't have code.